# React how to wait until state is updated without extra state variables?

Tags: reactjs

I cannot understand. To cut it short, I have these 2 variables which are being used in the state

```
questionLoaded
gameOver
```

This component needs to wait until it finishes getting data using the function `selectRandomQuestion`.

Therefore if i remove the `questionLoaded`, it will give me exception when it's looping through the map.

Now I had to create another variable to check when the game is over to unrender this component, therefore the terniary condition `questionLoaded || gameOver ?`

I tried checking the variable `currentQuestion` to conditionally render, but for some reason it will give exception when looping through the map in the `options` array of this property. Which means `currentQuestion` gets data first before it's own child property `options` has any data when hitting the condition check

The problem is that this looks kind of dirty, I'm still using react just for a few weeks and I'm not sure if this is the appropriate way to deal with state updates or is there a better way to handle it.

To sum it up, my problem is when rendering components, I often need to wait for the state to update when the rendering depends on some conditions, and everytime I need a new condition that means I need another set of logic using another state variable. Which means creating another `useEffect` with extra logic and to be triggered when that variable is updated.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './GuessPicture.css';
import questions from './data/questions.js';

function GuessPicture() {
    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState({});
    const [unansweredQuestions, setUnansweredQuestions] = useState([]);
    const [answeredQuestions, setAnsweredQuestions] = useState([]);
    const [questionLoaded, setQuestionLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [gameOver, setGameOver] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setUnansweredQuestions(questions);
        selectRandomQuestion();
        setQuestionLoaded(true);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (unansweredQuestions.length > 0) nextQuestion();
        else alert('game over');
    }, [unansweredQuestions]);

    function selectRandomQuestion() {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);
        let selectedQuestion = questions[index];
        selectedQuestion.options = shuffle(selectedQuestion.options);
        setCurrentQuestion(selectedQuestion);
    }

    function nextQuestion() {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * unansweredQuestions.length);
        let selectedQuestion = unansweredQuestions[index];
        selectedQuestion.options = shuffle(selectedQuestion.options);
        setCurrentQuestion(selectedQuestion);
    }

    // Fisher Yates Shuffle Algorithm
    function shuffle(array) {
        var currentIndex = array.length,
            temporaryValue,
            randomIndex;

        // While there remain elements to shuffle...
        while (0 !== currentIndex) {
            // Pick a remaining element...
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;

            // And swap it with the current element.
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
        }

        return array;
    }

    const onClickOption = (event) => {
        if (currentQuestion.correctValue == event.target.dataset.value) {
            setAnsweredQuestions((answeredQuestions) => [
                ...answeredQuestions,
                currentQuestion,
            ]);

            const newUnansweredQuestions = unansweredQuestions.filter(
                (item) => item.id != currentQuestion.id
            );

            setUnansweredQuestions(newUnansweredQuestions);
        } else alert('Wrong');
    };

    return (
        <>
            {questionLoaded || gameOver ? (
                <div className="guess-picture-container">
                    <div className="guess-picture">
                        <img src={currentQuestion.image} alt="English 4 Fun" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="guess-picture-answers-grid">
                        {currentQuestion.options.map((key) => (
                            <button
                                key={key.value}
                                onClick={onClickOption}
                                data-value={key.value}
                            >
                                {key.display}
                            </button>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            ) : null}
        </>
    );
}

export default GuessPicture;
```

Comment: Hooks are mostly just plain js code. However complex logic can go, there’s always way to clean code up. DRY, abstract at right level. You know these rules. One benefit of hooks, is that they’re just functions™️. So decoupling is easier. Pull them into other files, import them back to use inside the component, whatever suits you. I don’t think keep things clean is an issue with hooks.

Comment: I see, I thought everything would be easier if when updateing the state had a callback and could just run login after it

Comment: Well, the component function body per se is guaranteed to run after each update…so not quite sure what you want. Anything more specific?

Comment: Btw i think alike to Glen your current code LGTM. Except that I wouldn’t tuck all these functions inside component function, look crowded. But the code itself is fine.

Comment: @hackape I see, so any additional functions and logic should be in separated folders

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine to me, however I would avoid the ternary operator in this situation and use the short-circuit operator instead.  This makes your code a little cleaner.

instead of:

`{questionLoaded || gameOver ? <SomeComponentHere /> : null}`

try using:

`{(questionLoaded || gameOver) && <SomeComponentHere />}`

Why avoid the ternary operator?  Because it's not a ternary operation, it is a boolean check.  This makes your code more semantically appropriate.

Comment: So basically the more logic I have there is no way to make it cleaner? Because it seems overwhelming at some point the more logic is introduced and need to keep track of all the hooks

Comment: I would also move the Fisher-Yates algorithm to another file, probably in a utils folder.

Comment: My preferred style would be eager return like: `if (!questionLoaded || !gameOver) return null;` before return the component.

Comment: I do actually prefer the if guard, not a fan of having lots of brackets.